# Wife number 1001

Tags: purim, megillat-esther, esther--the-woman

I read on the website truthofland.co.il (I have no idea who write it) the following statement
וכן אסתר באה אל אחשוורוש בליל תקופת טבת. וכבר ראינו שהיא היתה אשה מס' 1001 אצל אחשורוש. נמצא שגאולת פורים וגאולת חנוכה צמחו מחשכת לילה הארוך בשנה

Basically, Esther was the ‘wife’ number 1001 of Achsverosh.

I could not find anything on truthofland about this nor could I find any source for this concept. Does anyone have a SOURCE for this? (or who runs the website I could ask them)

Comment: Almost wonder if that was influenced by Scheherazade ...

Comment: two papers were written by the same guy -- maybe look him up מאת פרופ' דניאל מיכלסון, מחלקה למדעי המחשב ומתמטיקה שמושית, מכון ויצמן

Comment: No idea of a source but it always seemed like Achsovros had a lot  more than one wife. He seemed to have barely  even known Esther as evidenced by the fact that she hadn't seen  him for the past thirty days and was so scared to approach him. Given what a  philanderer he was must have have seen other wives during the time

Comment: @Schmerel He definitely had a lot of concubines, but it seems like he only had one official queen.

Comment: The website is fascinating, but the author seems very comfortable making huge assumptions of fact.